# How to solve message tag error in wsdl file?

Tags: java, xml, wsdl

I am new to wsdl file. I don't know to solve this error in message tag.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<definitions
    name="ApplicationService"
    targetNamespace="http://com/regulusgroup/t2/application/service/ApplicationService"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://com/regulusgroup/t2/application/service/ApplicationService"
    xmlns:app="http://com/regulusgroup/t2/ApplicationInfo">

    <import namespace="http://com/regulusgroup/t2/ApplicationInfo" location="@config.protocol@@config.server@@config.port@@config.root@/xsd/Application.xsd" />

    <message name="getSubAppsRequest">
        <part name="getSubAppsRequest" element="app:getSubAppsRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="getSubAppsResponse">
        <part name="return" element="app:getSubAppsResponse"/>
    </message>
....

<binding name="ApplicationServiceBinding" type="tns:ApplicationServicePort">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
...
</binding>

<service name="ApplicationService">
        <port name="ApplicationServicePort" binding="tns:ApplicationServiceBinding">
            <soap:address location="@config.protocol@@config.server@@config.port@@config.root@/ApplicationService"/>
        </port>
    </service>

</definitions>
```

I got "The part 'getSubAppsRequest' has an invalid value 'getSubAppsRequest' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a  schema." error in message tag.

getSubAppsRequest is a class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "getSubAppsRequest")
public class GetSubAppsRequest {
}
```

Comment: `getSubAppsRequest` is defined as message name and same is defined as the element in below line. so you have to change the element matches to the return type data/other service/operation.

Comment: @mallikarjun I have included the class GetSubAppsRequest  declared, Is it matches with the element?